# Find 3 coordinates on 2d wrapping grid where maximum distance to any of the three from any point of the grid is shortest.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I hope the title is clear enough...

Given a two dimensional square grid of size `x`.

The grid wraps around so (x+1, x+1) is equal to (0,0)

Given point A(a,a) what are the coordinates of B and C so that the maximum distance from any given point to any of A, B or C is the shortest.

To clarify only the distance to the closest point from any given coordinate of the grid is relevant.

---

I know that for two points the solution would be B(a + x/2, a + x/2) but can't quite wrap my head around how to approach this problem with 3 locations.

Comment: Since I only needed this for a 150x150 grid I brute-forced the solution to be `[ x, y ] [ x+47, y+47 ] [ x+98, y+98 ]`. I would still appreciate if anyone could help me find a more elegant solution to this problem.